# KVM 2 VMs on one disk

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, linux-kvm, virtual-disk

Is it possible to create 2 VMs that share a CPU and 1 virtual disk (using KVM)? If so how would I go about it? I've looked online, but can't really find something that works in the command line.

Comment: Can you clarify your question - specifically what do you mean by "single disk" - Are you wanting 2 VMs to use 1 disk image or are you asking his you can have  multiple VMS on a host with 1 drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for 2 VMs to share a single disk. In order to use it, however, you have to use a cluster aware file system designed for this. Commonly used ones include:

- GFS / GFS2 (RedHat)
- OCFS / OCFS2 (Oracle)
- VMFS (VMware)

These were intended to be used with SANs, but they can also be used with DRBD and VMs (host is the SAN in that context. This works similarly to how NFS / CIFS can be used with a NAS.

You can even use these as your root file system, though you would need additional tooling which is, unfortunately, no longer available. Once upon a time (RHEL5 days) there was something called Open Shared Root which provided the tooling to set this up, and I contributed various patches to it back in the day (support for rootfs on iSCSI and GlusterGS). Unfortunately, OSR seems to have disappeared off the internet since, and it was never updated for EL7 and later.

As for how to do it with KVM, use a raw block device for the virtual disk (disk, partition, LVM device mapper volume, ZFS zvol, etc).